# Javascript alert coming up when not expected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to ensure that all fields of a form are not empty. When there are empty fields this alert comes up as expected, however when all fields are full the alert still comes up. Am I missing something?

```
var sn = document.myForm.address.length;
var sna = document.myForm.street.length;
var su = document.myForm.city.length;
var st = document.myForm.state.length;
var usn = document.myForm.username.length;

if (sn || sna || su || st || usn == null) {
    alert("All fields are required. Please ensure you leave no fields blank."); 
    return false;   
} else {

}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1avngwru/1/  Change your if statement....

Comment: Still happening @nevermind

Comment: Yes, because length of DOM element will return undefined... Check for values, instead: http://jsfiddle.net/33tsbg2g/

Comment: P.S. I am assuming that you have similar HTML structure, and that address points to input with name address, and so on... but you need values...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you initialized all your variables, your `if` statement is evaluating true like this:

`if (true || true || true || true || true || false)`

Only one `true` makes the entire `if` condition above evaluate to `true` because all the `||` operators are `OR` operators.

Consider further, if you simply *declare* but do not *initialize* a variable for example `var sn; //declared` as opposed to `var sn = document.myForm.address.length; //initialized` then its condition evaluates to `false` because `if(sn)` is declared but not initialized = false`.

Moreover, to check the value inside each variable rather than whether or not they are initialized, you must do this:

`if (sn == null || sna == null || su == null || st == null || usn == null)`

or possibly since you're assigned a length you want this

`if (sn > 0 || sna > 0 || su > 0` etc...

Comment: Right, I guess i'm getting a little confused. What would be the proper way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Hmm it's still happening

Comment: It's so weird i'm still getting the error uhh. Thanks for the clatity though I understand it but it's till not working